# proving $\sqrt[n+1]{ab^n} \le \frac{a+nb}{n+1}$ where $a,b \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove $$\sqrt[n+1]{ab^n} \le \frac{a+nb}{n+1}$$ for $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$

I don't really need a solution but an advice on how I can approach this problem, just so that it gets me in the right direction.

Also are there some general approaches you would suggest on dealing with these kind of problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is just the AM-GM inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by AM-GM we get
$$\sqrt[n+1]{a\cdot b\cdots b}\le \frac{a+b+\cdots+b}{n+1}$$ with $n\times b$ (n times b)

Comment: I tried that, and my first intuition led me doing this actually, but I got confused since the letters and b are different. But the AM-GM just says n numbers multiplied. I think this just changed how I think about terms in math. Danke!

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Young's inequality*: if $x,y \ge 0$, $p,q > 1$, and $\dfrac 1p + \dfrac 1q = 1$, then $$xy \le \frac{x^p}p + \frac{y^q}{q}.$$

Further hint hidden below if you want to give it a try first.

> In your case, $x = a^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$, $y = b^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$, $p = n+1$, and $q = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$.

Comment: This is the continuous extension of AM-GM inequality and is algebraically equivalent to it in case $p, q$ are rational.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: express $a+nb=a+\underbrace{b+\cdots+b}_{n}$